# Why aren't all users in a country listed in this SEDE query? (Character encoding issues?)

Tags: support, data-explorer, unicode

I am using [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1052739/top-users-by-country) data.stackexchange query to list the top users in Bulgaria. The result I get is as follows

```
#    DisplayName                    User Link                      tt     
---- ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------ 
1    Darin Dimitrov                 Darin Dimitrov                 867221 
2    Bozho                          Bozho                          500616 
3    Ivan Stoev                     Ivan Stoev                     116955 
4    Tsvetomir Tsonev               Tsvetomir Tsonev               93237  
5    Ivaylo Strandjev               Ivaylo Strandjev               57663  
6    Konstantin Yovkov              Konstantin Yovkov              53924  
7    Bozhidar Batsov                Bozhidar Batsov                47226  
8    Milen A. Radev                 Milen A. Radev                 46339  
9    npocmaka                       npocmaka                       43155  
10   Petar Minchev                  Petar Minchev                  40948  
11   Blagovest Buyukliev            Blagovest Buyukliev            35284  
12   Vityata                        Vityata                        34061
```

and I noticed not all users are returned in this result. In fact, my [brother's account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1108032/boris-strandjev) should have been 11th but it is nowhere on the list. He specified his location the same way as I did, so I wonder why I am present and he is not.

Comment: Did he change the location entry recently? SEDE is only a snapshot that is taken once a week, so the data might not be available if the change is recent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your [brother is not in Bulgaria](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1079486):

[image]

At least he wasn't at Sunday around 03:00 UTC when SEDE was last refreshed.

I had hoped I could get this somehow to work by offering a second selection option [like I did here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1079551/top-users-by-country?CountryName=bulgaria&CountryNameAlternative=0x11044a043b0433043004400438044f04) but it turns out SEDE doesn't send `България` as is to the server. It looks like it uses a far stricter encoding.

To make it fly I have to send the varbinary encoding of 'България' to SEDE and if you do this query will also return users that uses the cyrilic version:

```
-- Top Users by Country / Hexcode Alternative country
-- Original by samliew (http://stackoverflow.com/users/584192/samuel-liew)

SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Reputation DESC) AS [#], 
    DisplayName,
    Id AS [User Link], 
    Reputation tt
    --,*
FROM
    Users
WHERE
    Location LIKE '%##CountryName##%' collate SQL_latin1_general_cp1_ci_ai
OR  Location LIKE concat('%'
                  , case 
                    when left(##CountryNameAlternative:string## ,2) = '0x'
                    then convert(nvarchar,convert(varbinary, ##CountryNameAlternative:string##,1)) 
                    else
                      ##CountryNameAlternative:string## 
                    end
                  ,'%')  collate SQL_latin1_general_cp1_ci_ai
ORDER BY
    Reputation DESC;
```

Unfortunately there isn't an (easy) way to make SEDE produce the HEX representation of those Cyrillic characters.

[image: SEDE parameters for country and alternative country with hexcoding of 0x11044a043b0433043004400438044f04]

Comment: You are right of course! It turns out it is only yesterday that my brother changed the cyrilic version to the latin one and most probably it still is not updated. I did not notice the different way the country was written. An interesting observation is that if I enter "България" in the search term he is not listed either.